# Shutting up KDE applications launched from the command line

Tags: linux, terminal, kde, gui

Whenever I launch a KDE application from the command line, for instance okular to view a pdf, I get spammed with tons of warnings and various messages that I am not interested in. Even hours after I shut the program I get random messages in that terminal. Here is a sample:

```
kded(26751)/kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) KCoreConfigSkeleton::writeConfig:
kded(26751)/kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) KCoreConfigSkeleton::writeConfig:
kded(26751)/kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) KCoreConfigSkeleton::writeConfig:
kded(26751)/kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) KCoreConfigSkeleton::writeConfig:
```

You get the idea. How can I turn this behavior off for *all* KDE applications without having to append something like `>/dev/null` every single time?

I'm using KDE 4.4.5.

Comment: Is everything disabled in `kdebugdialog`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'd just shut the programs up by `2>/dev/null`. Either you have to throw *all* error messages for all applications, or keep a list of binary names somewhere with the programs you want to be quiet.

To keep the list, you could e.g. put overloading scripts in your `PATH` with names corresponding to the binaries, e.g. `okular`:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/okular "${@}" 2>/dev/null
```

Alternatively, you could create a script called e.g. `q` (for quiet) and put it in your path with contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
"${@}" 2>/dev/null
```

and then add aliases such as

```
alias okular="q okular"
```

and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Run
    kdebugdialog

Check if
kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) is checked. 
If yes, uncheck it, and the debug output should disappear.

Reference: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=612597